# Identify Distinct of two columns and not present in another column -

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

**Background (and the requirement):**
There is a table "T_CLASS" with multiple columns of which two are student names ex. Student1 and Student2. There's another table "T_STUDENT" where I want to check against T_CLASS, to get the distinct students from columns T_CLASS which doesn't exist in T_STUDENT table.

Also I would like to mention, the table contains circa 600M records each.

**Sample query (and my attempt):**

```
;with t_class(id, student1, student2) as (
    select 1, 'Tom', 'Rahul' union all
    select 2, 'Rahul', 'Nick' union all
    select 3, 'David', 'Mark' union all
    select 4, 'Rahul', 'Mark' union all
    select 5, 'Rick', 'David'
)
, t_student (c_student) as (
        select 'David' union all
        select 'Nick' union all
        select 'Mark' union all
        select 'Rick' 
)
-- Below is what I've tried --
select student1
from t_class crt
where not exists
    (
        select 1 from t_student djt
        where lower(trim(crt.student1)) = lower(trim(djt.c_student))
    )
union
select student2
from t_class crt
where not exists
    (
        select 1 from t_student djt
        where lower(trim(crt.student2)) = lower(trim(djt.c_student))
    )
```

**Expected o/p:**

```
Rahul
Tom
```

Note: I don't want any specific query as solution, but I want to understand it conceptually.

But is this a good technique or there can be any other optimal approach? I know I've to try out the ways and check execution plan, but can't think of any.

Please advise. Thanks in advance. :)

ps. Got this exec plan generated from SQL Server 2016 (however this query is actually on AWS Redshift) -

[image]

---

Edit 2 - Meanwhile I've tried another attempt ...

```
;with t_class(id, student1, student2) as (
    select 1, 'Tom', 'Rahul' union all
    select 2, 'Rahul', 'Nick' union all
    select 3, 'David', 'Mark' union all
    select 4, 'Rahul', 'Mark' union all
    select 5, 'Rick', 'David'
)
, t_student (c_student) as (
        select 'David' union all
        select 'Nick' union all
        select 'Mark' union all
        select 'Rick' 
)
select * from
(
select student1 studs from t_class
union 
select student2 from t_class
) x
where not exists (select 1 from t_student ts where ts.c_student = x.studs)
```

Is this any better?
**Execution plan**:
[image]

Comment: It is better to implement the WHERE EXIST condition in another way
Because there is no suitable algorithm for its implementation by Query Optimizer
My suggestion is to use 'Join'
In this way, the main table is merged with the Student 1 column and after Student 2 column, and then the null condition is checked.
This allows you to use better algorithms for comparison

Comment: Thanks @SaeedEmamYari. I've added edit 2 with another approach and it's exec plan. I'm still evaulating.

Comment: Another edit: both the tables contains circa 600M records each.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Z.STUDENT_NAME
(
 SELECT C.STUDENT1 AS STUDENT_NAME
    FROM T_CLASS AS C
  UNION 
 SELECT X.STUDENT2
   FROM T_CLASS AS X 
)AS Z
EXCEPT 
SELECT T.c_student
FROM T_STUDENT AS T
```

I hope, you can try this approach. It can be simplified, but I don't exactly remember the precedence of UNION/EXCEPT/INTERSECT-operators

Comment: It's bit similar to my 2nd query attempt, where I'm doing the UNION first in CLASS table. I've posted the execution plan above if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

in postgresSQL you can do this to get students that are in Students and do not exist in Class.

```
SELECT name
        FROM Students S
        WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                           FROM Class C  
                           WHERE S.sid = C.sid)
```

Comment: But there are 2 columns I've to look into in T_CLASS table, that's the tricky part :)

Comment: can't you just add (firstCondition AND secondCondition) in front of subQuery?